# Does move semantics of C++11 overperfom copy-on-write idiom?

Tags: c++, c++11, idioms

I might be confusing here but what I did understand is that :

- COW will return a "fake" copy until one of the callers want to make some modifications.
- Move Semantic will return a "fake" copy in all cases.

So if my purpose is to have an object that only need to be read and not updated, I should only wait for move semantics support in my C++ compilers ?

Am I right ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Move semantics does not return a "fake" copy. Instead, in a copy operation, it gives the copyee permission to trash the original copy.

A motivating example may be instructive:

```
std::vector<int> bigData;

// fill bigData

std::vector<std::vector<int> > listOfData;

listOfData.push_back(std::move(bigData));
// after this point, the contents of bigData are unspecified (however accessing it is _not_ undefined behavior)
```

Without move semantics, you'd need to copy `bigData` to insert it into listOfData, or manually twiddle with `swap()` into a new empty vector that's in listOfData. But with move semantics, the rvalue-reference-constructor (aka move constructor) of `std::vector`, invoked by `push_back` as it copies in the new data, has permission to trash the old contents of `bigData` - thus, it's allowed to steal `bigData`'s internal pointer and reset `bigData` to an empty vector, for example.

Move semantics are usually faster than COW semantics as they don't need to maintain reference counts to shared, read-only data. They are, however, more limited - you can't create multiple reference-counted aliases to your data with move semantics, you can just easily and conveniently shuffle data between containers.

Also note that both recent versions of GCC and Microsoft Visual C++ support rvalue references and move semantics (GCC with `--std=c++0x`), so there's no reason not to start using them today.

Comment: defining trash: An unknown but **valid** state.

Comment: "the contents of bigData are unspecified (however accessing it is _not_ undefined behavior)" - so the result is defined by the type being copied, in its move constructor? Will `std::move` fall back on a copy constructor if no move constructor is defined? Or perhaps on `std::swap`?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel: `std::move` does not move anything. All it does is convert it to a `T&&` r-value reference, which can trigger calling the move constructor (or move assignment operator). It is the move constructor that actually does the moving. Default move constructors will be created, just like default copy constructors. The default move constructor moves each element by itself. For basic types, the default move is just a copy. For user-defined types, it's a call to the move constructor.

Answer (score 1):

copy-on-write and move constructors are different things.

Let's speak about strings where COW implementations are widespread. Let's say you have string implementation that supports COW and move semantic. Consider this code then:

```
cow::string foo() { return string("foo"); } // move CTOR is in effect here.

cow::string a = foo(); // move ctor in effect
cow::string b = a; // copy ctor in effect
```

`a` and `b` here will share the same allocated sequence of chars. While here

```
std::string foo() { return string("foo"); } // move CTOR is in effect here.

std::string a = foo(); // move ctor in effect
std::string b = a; // copy ctor in effect
```

`a` and `b` will allocate and hold two different sequences of chars doubling memory consumption.

Comment: My understanding is that COW implementations for strings, while obvious, are not actually widespread, because people found that they destroy performance in multithreaded environments.

Comment: Karl, do you have any practical prove of the statement "they destroy performance in multi-threaded environments"? It sounds as an urban myth these days with these processors, etc.

Yes, InterlockedIncrement & friends do create some overhead but otherwise additional heap allocation also require some synchronization primitives in multithread environment. It is not clear what is worse. In any case it is very case-by-case dependent.

Comment: I couch statements in phrases like "My understanding is that" and "[other] people found" for a good reason. ;)

Comment: We had bad experience with COW, dynamic memory allocation and locks. COW strings not always good in a multithreaded environment